# C# multithreaded windows form with multiple embedded web browsers

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

There is an open source windows form client for [Xibo](http://xibo.org.uk) that contains embedded web browsers. The problem is that while one web browser is getting busy, the other browsers and controls in the form can't respond and they actually pause. So I thought maybe it is a good idea to have one thread for each web browser with it's own application message loop. But it seems unsafe to add controllers created in different threads to a single form. In fact I was lucky to have some browsers in different threads by a few lines of code refactor before I realized it actually should not work at all!

Is it a good way to make it possible? What is the best solution to make such an application multithreaded with minimum coding?

Comment: Hmm, no, browsers and threads are fire and water.  This is surely a more systemic problem with a browser executing an unreasonable amount of "Xibo" scripting code that bogs everything down.  Ping the vendor about this.

Comment: Are you sure that, rather than having a buggy 3rd party control, you aren't just using it inappropriately in a way that blocks the UI thread instead?  You should really avoid multiple UI threads at all costs if possible.

Comment: I can have browsers in single-threaded-apartment-state treads.

Comment: There is precedent for this sort of approach, if I understand correctly - Google Chrome has managed to partition UI work to separate processes per tab ("web control" in this case), and then composites them into a single UI experience. IIRC, they do this for security, but I'd also imagine that it helps scale rendering across multiple CPUs. I do generally agree that multithreading UI is a task for only the most careful .. but it seems like there's precedent.

Comment: @antiduh Somehow I imagine that the OP might not have the resources to put to a task like this that Google does.

Comment: I am not sure of xibo code or ie code. but i think there is no bug related to my problem. Web pages can be heavy. Moreover, beside web browsers, there are mulitmedia players as well. if there is a solution for web browsers, i can apply it to other parts as well.

Comment: @Servy Hey I did say "I do generally agree that multithreading UI is a task for only the most careful". Just trying to be a little constructive :)

Comment: Can I tell .net core, or whatever, somehow I know what I am doing, please don't throw exception while i am adding one controller to another controller of different thread!? :P

Comment: @HamidAlaei In a way, yes. But the fact that you have to ask suggests you *don't* actually know what you're doing quite yet :D

Comment: I am thinking of a new controller that proxies a web browser controller. Then it actually create a new form that is rendered just above it and inside that there is a web browser. I am thinking who can I proxy every call to methods of web browser. Or how for example I move the web browser when the original form is moving.

Comment: @HamidAlaei By the sounds of what you're doing it *won't* work, and you're *not* ensuring that the information accessed from these seperate threads is properly synchronized, so the fact that you're getting an exception to tell you that it won't work, instead of having a program filled with lots of subtle bugs, race conditions, unreliability, etc. you at least know that your program isn't written correctly.

Comment: :( I may go for that proxy idea anyway. In my proxy controller i try to take care of every inter-thread regulations!